# How to improve my feature selection for a NB classifier?

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I have read that improving feature selection will reduce the training time of my classifier and also improve accuracy but I am not sure how can I reduce the number of features. Should I count them and after select the first 3000 for example ?

This is my code :

```
def save_object(obj, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(obj,output,pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        print "saved"
        ujson.dumps({"output" : "obj"})


with open('neg5000.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    neg_tweets = list(reader)
    print "list ready"

with open('pos5000.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    pos_tweets = list(reader)
    print "list ready"

tweets = []
for (words, sentiment) in pos_tweets + neg_tweets:
    words_filtered = [e.lower() for e in words.split() if len(e) >= 3] 
    tweets.append((words_filtered, sentiment))




def get_words_in_tweets(tweets):
    all_words = []
    for (words, sentiment) in tweets:
      all_words.extend(words)
    return all_words

def get_word_features(wordlist):
    wordlist = nltk.FreqDist(wordlist)
    word_features = list(wordlist.keys())[:3000]
    #word_features = wordlist.keys()
    return word_features

def extract_features(document):
    document_words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for word in word_features:
        features['contains(%s)' % word] = (word in document_words)
    return features
#def extract_features(words):
 #   return dict([(word, True) for word in words])


word_features = get_word_features(get_words_in_tweets(tweets))
training_set = nltk.classify.apply_features(extract_features, tweets)


save_object(word_features, 'wordf.save')
print 'features done'
print datetime.datetime.now()
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
print 'training done'
print datetime.datetime.now()

save_object(classifier, 'classifier.save')

tweet = 'I love this car'
print classifier.classify(extract_features(tweet.split()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways to approach feature selection for the supervised classification problem (which is what Naive Bayes does). I suggest heading over to `scikit-learn` [manual](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) and just trying everything listed there, since the choice of particular method is dependends on the data you have.

The easiest way to do this is to switch to the [`scikit-learn` implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html) of Naive Bayes and the use a [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html) to chain the feature selection and classifier training. See this [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) for code examples.

Here's a version of your code using `scikit-learn` with [`SelectKBest`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html) feature selection:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


def read_input(path):
    with open(path) as handle:
        lines = (line.rsplit(",", 1) for line in handle)
        return [text for text, label in lines]


# Assuming each line in ``neg5000.csv`` and ``pos5000.csv`` is a
# UTF-8-encoded tweet.
neg_tweets = read_input("neg5000.csv")
pos_tweets = read_input("pos5000.csv")

X = np.append(neg_tweets, pos_tweets)
y = np.append(np.full(len(neg_tweets), -1, dtype=int),
              np.full(len(pos_tweets), 1, dtype=int))


p = Pipeline([
    ("vectorizer", CountVectorizer()),
    ("selector", SelectPercentile(percentile=20)),
    ("nb", MultinomialNB())
])

p.fit(X, y)
print(p.predict(["I love this car"]))
```

Comment: Would it be possible in my implementation just to reduce the features as I don't have time to start again with a new implementation using scikit-learn?

Comment: In this case you will have to implement the methods manually, which might be more painful then switching to `scikit-learn`. I've updated the answer with a code sample.

Comment: I have tried to run the code after installing the libraries and now I get this error : 'RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  f = msb / msw
[ 1.] ' any ideea what can it be ?

Comment: Can you please include the filename and the line number producing the warning?

Comment: full error :`C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:294: FutureWarning: in the future, full(5001, -1) will return an array of dtype('int32')
  format(shape, fill_value, array(fill_value).dtype), FutureWarning)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:294: FutureWarning: in the future, full(5001, 1) will return an array of dtype('int32')
  format(shape, fill_value, array(fill_value).dtype), FutureWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newtry.py", line 24, in <module>
    ("selector", SelectKBest(chi2, k=100)),
NameError: name 'chi2' is not defined`

Comment: I have tried on a different machine and now it is giving me this : `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py:113: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  f = msb / msw
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py:319: UserWarning: Duplicate scores. Result may depend on feature ordering.There are probably duplicate features, or you used a classification score for a regression task.
  warn("Duplicate scores. Result may depend on feature ordering."
[ 1.]`

Comment: can it be my files ? neg5000 looks like this :  Awww, that's a bummer.  You shoulda got David Carr of Third Day to do it. ;D, neg
is upset that he can't update his Facebook by texting it... and might cry as a result  School today also. Blah!, neg
 I dived many times for the ball. Managed to save 50%  The rest go out of bounds, neg
my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire , neg

Comment: It is possible that the word frequencies in your data aren't enough to do chi2 test reliably, e.g. each class has a single occurrence. Try using a different criterion.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with different criterion. [link](http://www.filedropper.com/neg5000) , [link](http://www.filedropper.com/pos5000) , I have attached my training data can you give it a try and check if it is working on your side ?

Comment: Yes, the issue is in the way I'm reading the input. I'll update the answer in a minute.

Comment: Thank you for the update this works briliant. One more question is there any workaround for this to calculate if a tweet is neutral for example in my initial code I was planning to use something like this : `class_prob = self.sentiment_classifier.prob_classify(features).prob(class_label)
    return class_label if class_prob > 0.6 else 'neutral'`

Comment: I'm not sure what would be the best way of including neutrality, but it is possible to implement your idea in `scikit-learn`: extract class probabilities from the classifier by calling [`predict_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.predict_proba) and then apply the threshold using [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).